# How does Dart VM work in flutter app when debugging?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, frontend

I'm a native iOS developer, learning Flutter recently. I learned from some flutter's tutorials that Dart supports both AOT and JIT, and when the app is compiled for Release, the Dart code is compiled to machine code through AOT, and when debugging, Dart code will be executed through JIT, with a Dart VM, which will make hot-reload possible.

My question is how the Dart VM works when debugging? Take iOS app for example, as iOS app is running in its own sand box, where is the Dart VM running? Is the VM running inside the app's process? Maybe it's like a sub-thread running in the background and keep interpreting the Dart code to machine code just in time when the app is running?

Answer (score 2):

The Dart VM is written in C++, and there is only a relatively small section of Flutter written in iOS, called the shell. For iOS, you can find the files [in this directory of Flutter/engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine/tree/master/shell/platform/darwin/ios). I am still just learning/ browsing the Flutter internals myself.

To answer your questions, a Dart VM is shared between all isolates, and runs in your app **process**. There can only be 1 Dart VM running in a process, a design of the Dart VM (instead of constructing it, you ask for one, and it gives you the same one aka. Singleton pattern). A normal flutter app is one single isolate, but you could run multiple Flutter Engines/ Dart entrypoints (`main` methods) in a single iOS process/ app. The Dart VM manages isolates, so it does not run in one thread. From reading [mrale.ph/dartvm](https://mrale.ph/dartvm/), internally, it uses a thread pool and manages OS threads, so it definitely not limited to one thread.

> The relationship between OS threads and isolates is a bit blurry and highly dependent on how VM is embedded into an application.

> Internally VM uses a thread pool (dart::ThreadPool) to manage OS threads and the code is structured around dart::ThreadPool::Task concept rather than around a concept of an OS thread.

---

## For more investigation

Read https://mrale.ph/dartvm/ **and** you could clone the [Flutter/engine project](https://github.com/flutter/engine) and look for `FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE` string, and see the logic changes in Flutter between debug, profile, release and JIT release.

### For example, in the Dart VM ([`dart_vm.cc`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/runtime/dart_vm.cc)):

```c
#if (FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE == FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE_DEBUG)
#if !OS_IOS && !OS_MACOSX
  // Debug mode uses the JIT, disable code page write protection to avoid
  // memory page protection changes before and after every compilation.
  PushBackAll(&args, kDartWriteProtectCodeArgs,
              fml::size(kDartWriteProtectCodeArgs));
#else
  const bool tracing_result = EnableTracingIfNecessary(settings_);
  // This check should only trip if the embedding made no attempts to enable
  // tracing. At this point, it is too late display user visible messages. Just
  // log and die.
  FML_CHECK(tracing_result)
      << "Tracing not enabled before attempting to run JIT mode VM.";
#if TARGET_CPU_ARM
  // Tell Dart in JIT mode to not use integer division on armv7
  // Ideally, this would be detected at runtime by Dart.
  // TODO(dnfield): Remove this code
  // https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24743
  PushBackAll(&args, kDartDisableIntegerDivisionArgs,
              fml::size(kDartDisableIntegerDivisionArgs));
#endif  // TARGET_CPU_ARM
#endif  // !OS_IOS && !OS_MACOSX
#endif  // (FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE == FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE_DEBUG)
```

### Or, in the `FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.mm`:

You can see if the application was running in debug, a background task (`_debugBackgroundTask`) is cancelled when the app enters the foreground. This `_debugBackgroundTask` was created when the app enters the background, to keep the Flutter session alive when the device screen locks. More information [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/0ba39de139a209d124f52d7a0c692cb745fa4a44/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate.mm#L137-L167).

```
- (void)handleWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification*)notification {
  UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
#if FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE == FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE_DEBUG
  if (_debugBackgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:_debugBackgroundTask];
    _debugBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  }
#endif  // FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE == FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE_DEBUG
  for (NSObject<FlutterApplicationLifeCycleDelegate>* delegate in _delegates) {
    if (!delegate) {
      continue;
    }
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)]) {
      [delegate applicationWillEnterForeground:application];
    }
  }
}
```